# Weird geometry appears when I switch to object mode. How can I make it dissapear?

Tags: modeling, objects

I only used a mirror modifier. How do I make it look like in edit mode?
[image: Edit mode vs object mode]

Comment: Enable the on-cage switch of the mirror modifier. This will insure that the edit mode display matches the object mode display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing an ALT-H (unhide) in Edit mode. It's possible that you hid some geometry while you were in Edit mode and it showed up in Object mode.

Comment: Thanks, this solved my problem.